# How to substitute a phrase with dollar mark with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

For substitution of a phrase I simply use:

```
sed -i "s:phrase_to_be_matched*:phrase_to_be_replaced_with:g" file_name
```

This works fine, until i have the following problem:

I have a line in a file,

```
#$ModLoad imudp
```

What i want,

```
$ModLoad imudp
```

I am currently running this,

```
sed -i "s:.*$ModLoad imudp.*:$ModLoad imudp:g" file
```

But i am getting:

```
 imudp
```

I know, this is happening because, `$ModLoad imudp` is considered as a variable, and as it doesn't exist I am getting this output.

I have tried with `"$ModLoad imudp"` too, but got the same result.

I can't simply remove the`#` because, i have other commented line in my file.

How to resolve this?

Comment: May I know by whom and why this is down voted? strange

Comment: I didn't down vote it but I assume it was because it's SUCH a common question that just the tiniest bit of effort on your pat of googling or searching this site or glancing at a sed book or a sed man page or any other documentation would produce the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using single quotes `''` instead of double quotes.

```
sed -i 's:.*$ModLoad imudp.*:$ModLoad imudp:g' file
```

This prevents special meaning of `$` for variable expansion.

**Edit:** (*as per @tripleee's comment*)

Also escape `$` for matching literal dollar sign

```
sed -i 's:.*\$ModLoad imudp.*:$ModLoad imudp:g' file
```

Comment: But that doesn't change the fact that `$` in a regex means end of line.  It does not match a literal dollar sign.

Comment: @tripleee Agree. Edited ans. But without escaping also, regex worked. Now I'm wondering how!

Comment: @jkshah - `$` matches EOL only at the end of a regex. Otherwise it matches dollar character.